# Leaflet Measure plugin to Sidebar-v2 via HTML

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, sidebar

In my sidebar, I am trying to hover over an icon and have the measure function activated. End result will show the measure GUI once hovered over. Demo displays the working plugin NOT in the sidebar.
http://ljagis.github.io/leaflet-measure/
I would like to have the same result once I hover over the icon in the sidebar html. "where I would like the measure function to be called and used" is activated through onclick.

```
<div class="sidebar-tabs">
  <ul role="tablist">
        <li><a title="Measure" role="tab" target="_blank"  onclick="where I would like measure function to be called and used"><i class="fa fa-pencil"> </i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js and css for measure can be found here:
https://github.com/ljagis/leaflet-measure

Thank you for helping!